# is there a way to nail hardwood floor where ceiling meets floor at 45 degree angle

Tags: hardwood-floor, installation, nails

I am putting in hardwood flooring in a room that has a sloping ceiling that meets the floor at 45 degrees.  It's not very useful space, and at some point I will build a knee wall and storage cabinets of some sort.  However, in the meantime, I want to extend the floor all the way to the corner of wall and ceiling.

There is obviously very little space to work (e.g. 8" away from corner has 8" of clearance above).  I have enough room to swing a hammer to blind nail and then top nail most rows, but as I get close to the edge, I don't think I will even be able to top nail the last couple of rows.

Is there a clever trick that I am unaware of?  Is there a way to nail them?  Or is my only option to glue?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd probably use a pneumatic trim nailer with 2" 16 ga. nails. They're not ring shank, but you shouldn't see much foot traffic there. Curious what better options exist.

Comment: pre-drill, use the hammer sideways. if you can wedge into the wall corner, you can use a metal bar (like a prybar) as a lever to pound in the last nails.

Comment: @isherwood i have a 16 ga nailer but it won't quite fit - good idea though.

Comment: @dandavis - that's a good idea.  nails might have to angle a little toward the corner  (opposite of direction they normally slant in when driven through tongue) but...so be it

Comment: I'd use the nail gun slightly tilted before I'd go whacking at it with a hammer.

Comment: dandavis's method is what I would suggest or to apply glue to the back of the last row. I hate houses where this is done - I am not sure if a remodeler did yours - but any builder that does it (aargh) Any of them try to get me to buy a house like that - I count that as WASTED useless space and would not even consider it.. even those half walls with a slanted ceiling - if I can't stand up all around the room - they can keep it. I definitely feel for you..  Of course you could build your knee wall now and make it easier to extend the flooring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the last rows you can nail in through the pre-drilled nail holes or with a nail gun. Toe nailing will not be critical here. The last 3 rows of any nail down floor I seen always has the last few rows surface nailed anyway. After that determine how much vertical space you have to the angled ceiling and rip a piece of material with an angle on the top to create a very short knee wall. Lay out the the rafters first to know where to nail the "knee wall". Do all the probing for the rafters if needed, behind the line that the knee wall will cover.